# Creating instances of an ability when there are multiple different type of abilities

Tags: design-patterns, python, object-oriented-design, data-structures, class-design

I'm creating an RPG game where a player has a set of skills, each of which he can level up to improve its effect. Here are two example skills:

- `health`: increase player's maximum health
- `regeneration`: slowly regenerate player's lost health back

Skills have many similar attributes, like `name`, `description`, `maximum_level`, and some event callbacks which tell what the skill should do, so I figured I should maybe create a class and these would be instances of it:

```
class Skill:
    def __init__(self, name, description, max_level, level=0):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.max_level = max_level
        self.level = level
        self.event_callbacks = {}

    def register_callback(self, event_name):
        def decorator(f):
             self.event_callbacks[event_name] = f
             return f
        return decorator

health_skill = Skill('health', 'increase player\'s maximum health', 8)

@health_skill.register_callback('player_spawn')
def on_player_spawn(skill, player):
    player.maximum_health += skill.level * 5

regeneration_skill = Skill('regeneration', 'regenerate player\'s lost health back', 8)

@regeneration_skill.register_callback('time_tick_second')
def on_second_tick(skill, player):
    if player.health < player.maximum_health:
        player.health = max(player.health + skill.level, player.maximum_health)

player.skills.extend([health_skill, regeneration_skill])
```

And this system works fine, but here's the problem: my game can have multiple players in it, and each of them needs its own instance of each skill. Now I need to somehow figure out a good structure where I can

1. create skills easily
2. create multiple instances of each skill easily

Any ideas of a good structure? Metaclasses? Subclassing? How do games usually do this?

**Edit:** This similar structure is used in many popular games like League of Legends, Dota 2, Hearthstone, etc... Another good example of this issue is heroes/champions in such games: each hero is similar and they obviously have a common base, yet each hero needs a lot of custom instance attributes like current health, mana, level, etc.

Comment: Once instance of per ability per player. Whats the issue?

Comment: How do I structure this? @marstato I basically need instances of instances. I'd also prefer not to have 20x memory used by storing the `name`, `description`, and `max_level` into every instance of a skill instance since they're always the same for the same kind of skills

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, i do not know the language you are using but i'll try using Java:

I'd create an interface `Skill` that you use outside of the skill-internal code. Then you can have an abstract class `DefaultSkill` that defines your common properties. You can then create a new skill class subclassing either `Skill` or `DefaultSkill` to implement special behaviour:

```
interface Skill {
    public String getName();
    public int getCurrentLevel();
    public int getMaximumLevel();

    public void onPlayerSpawn();
    public void onTick();
}

abstract class DefaultSkill implements Skill {
    private int currentLevel;
    private Player owningPlayer;

    public DefaultSkill(int startLevel, Player owningPlayer) {
        // .. assign to instance variables
    }
}

class HealthSkill extends DefaultSkill {

    public HealthSkill(Player player) {
        super(100, player);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return "Health";
    }

    public int getCurrentLevel() {
        return this.currentLevel;
    }

    public int getMaximumLevel() {
        return 100;
    }

    // implement onPlayerSpawn()
    // implement onTick()
}

Skill health = new HealthSkill(player);
```

You can take it one step further and separate skills and their development for each player:

```
interface Skill {
    public String getName();
    public int getMinimumLevel();
    public int getMaximumLevel();

    public void onPlayerSpawn(SkillDevelopment development, Player player);
    public void onTick(SkillDevelopment development, Player player);
}

interface SkillDevelopment {
    public Skill getSkill();
    public Player getPlayer();
    public int getCurrentLevel();
    public void setCurrentLevel(int level);

    public void onPlayerSpawn();
    public void onTick();
}

class DefaultSkillDevelopment implements SkillDevelopment {
    private int level;
    private Skill skill;
    private Player player;

    public DefaultSkillDevelopment(Skill skill, Player player, int startLevel) {
        // ...
    }

    public int getCurrentLevel() {
        return level;
    }

    public void setCurrentLevel(int level) {
        if (level < skill.getMinimumLevel() || level > skill.getMaximumLevel())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        this.level = level;
    }

    public void onPlayerSpawn() {
        skill.onPlayerSpawn(this, player);
    }

    public void onTick() {
        skill.onTick(this, player);
    }
}

class HealthSkill implements Skill {

    private static final HealthSkill INSTANCE = new HealthSkill();

    public static HealthSkill getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return "Health";
    }

    public int getMinimumLevel() {
        return 0;
    }

    public int getMaximumLevel() {
        return 100;
    }

    // implement onPlayerSpawn()
    // implement onTick()
}

SkillDevelopment health = new DefaultSkillDevelopment(HealthSkill.getInstance(), player);
```

Comment: Python doesn't have interfaces. The Python equivalent of an interface is nothing: you "implement an interface" by just implementing some methods, and you "accept an object implementing an interface" by accepting any object and assuming that it implements the relevant methods.

Comment: @TannerSwett too sad, didnt know that

Answer (score 0):

Creating only one skill class is, and then registering the callbacks with a decoration is an awkward pattern IMO. Just create a class for each skill. Each skill class directly adds the callbacks it needs. You can then give each player a set of skill objects instantiated from these classes.